# html text input value will not display full value because of " in the middle of it

Tags: html, mysql, forms

i have this HTML form input with the value

```
4gFX5\"Cf5
```

but its displaying like:

```
<input type="text" name="email_password" id="email_password" size="45" value="4gFX5\"Cf5" />
```

so the full value is not in the text field as there is a " in the middle of it.

it gets the value from a database - how can i stop this from happening?

Comment: I guess this would work... '4gFX5\"Cf5'

Comment: `htmlentities()` - might work when converted to `&quot;` (or use single quotes on the attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your output with html entities.

```
$value = '4gFX5\"Cf5';

<input type="text" name="email_password" id="email_password" size="45" value="<?php 
echo htmlentities($value);
?>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

if the values are 4gFX5\'Cf5 in that time you can use "" like this "4gFX5\'Cf5",
if the values are 4gFX5\"Cf5 in that time you can use '' like this '4gFX5\"Cf5'

Comment: This relies how the code is formatted in general. it could be a problem, when guidelines are violated.

Comment: Yes, using Escape function like L.Meyer wrote in his answer.

Comment: i tried L.Meyer coding too. thats shown the not exact result.. if u put double quote instead of single quote like this $value = "4gFX5\"Cf5"; output will be 4gFX5"Cf5. it does not display that back slash symbol in textbox. ???

Comment: That is now a php problem. you need to escape the \ by \\. Thats because you can enter in php with \t or \r\n tabs and return with line breaks. finally you have to escape for php and then escape for html.